# How to pass a function by reference in Objective C ?

Tags: objective-c, function, reference

I have the following method `-(void) displayQuestionWithAnswer: (int) answerNumber` in my ClassA and this has to be called from ClassB.

An object of ClassB is created in ClassA. How let ClassB to execute this specific method?

Thanks.

Comment: `[instanceOfClassA displayQuestionWithAnswer:someInt];` What, specifically, are you having a problem with?

Comment: if the instance of ClassB is made in instance of ClassA, how could ClassB can refer to ClassA instance? I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a method in the class it belongs to you use a reserved word `self` and use it like this:

```
[self someMethod];
```

P.S if I understood your task in a right way )